# Computing correlations between variables in 2 dataframes

Tags: r

Am trying to compute the correlations of the below countries, with USA. I have a relatively big dataset with 80+ variables & 3000+ observations in my first df as below, so am trying to use R to automate this instead of using excel.

I am trying to compute correlations for the countries in the first df (i.e. Germany, Italy, Japan and more) with USA in the 2nd df. So it should go Germany - USA, Italy - USA, Japan - USA and so on.

Not too sure how should I begin - should I loop every column in the first table to correlate with USA in the 2nd? Help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

df1

| Date | Germany | Italy | Japan | More countries... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2020 | 1000 | 200 | 2304 | More numbers... |
| 01-02-2020 | 2000 | 389 | 2098 | More numbers... |

and on and on

df2

| Date | USA |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2020 | 500 |
| 01-02-2020 | 600 |

and on and on

Comment: `as.data.frame(cor(df2[-1], df1[-1]))` or `as.data.frame(cor(df1[-1], df2[-1]))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this approach:

```
library(dplyr);library(magrittr)
countries = c("Germany", "Italy", "Japan")
left_join(df1, df2) %>% summarise(across(countries, ~cor(., USA)))
```

or, as the OP did not have access to the latest version of `dplyr` and `across()`:

```
left_join(df1, df2) %>% summarise_at(countries, ~cor(., USA))
```

1. `left_join` merges `df1` and `df2` together so that the dates always match up with one another
2. `summarise` allows you to perform column-wise operations
3. `across` tells you which columns you want to make a correlation with USA
4. `~cor(., USA)` says take each country and perform the correlation with USA

```
Germany  Italy  Japan
    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1  -0.393 -0.147 -0.214
```

Thank you Damien Georges for the data.

Comment: Was wondering if there's a way to do this without across()? My dplyr is unable to be updated to the latest version for across() to be available.

Comment: @AutumnWest what version of dplyr are you using?

Comment: 0.8.0; I am unable to upgrade...

Comment: @AutumnWest check the updates

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should do the trick:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- 
  tibble(
    date = 2001:2010,
    Germany = runif(10),
    Italy = runif(10),
    Japan = runif(10)
  )

df2 <-
  tibble(
    date = 2001:2010,
    USA = runif(10)
  )

df.cor <-
  df1 %>%
  summarise(across(-one_of('date'), ~ cor(.x, df2$USA)))

df.cor
```

Note: You have to be sure that dates are consistent between `df1` and `df2`. You can use join function (e.g. `left_join`) to ensure this

Answer (score 1):

Here are two base R solutions, depending on the final format you want.
Both with the new pipe operator, introduced in R 4.1.0.

```
df2[-1] |> cor(df1[-1]) |> as.data.frame()
#      Germany     Italy     Japan
#USA 0.3161338 0.5483885 0.1725733

df1[-1] |> cor(df2[-1]) |> as.data.frame()
#              USA
#Germany 0.3161338
#Italy   0.5483885
#Japan   0.1725733
```

More traditional but equivalent versions:

```
as.data.frame(cor(df2[-1], df1[-1]))
as.data.frame(cor(df1[-1], df2[-1]))
```

---

### Data

Data creation code borrowed from [Damien Georges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69558216/8245406).

```
set.seed(2021)
df1 <- 
  data.frame(
    date = 2001:2010,
    Germany = runif(10),
    Italy = runif(10),
    Japan = runif(10)
  )

df2 <-
  data.frame(
    date = 2001:2010,
    USA = runif(10)
  )
```